# What does (array) with two parentheses like this mean in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I've been reading some code recently and I've come across a few instances where the developer would wrap parentheses around like following example.

There's this function:

```
foreach ((array) $middleware as $m) {
    $this->middleware[] = [
    'middleware' => $m,
            'options' => &$options,
    ];
}
```

In the for each check there's array `(array)` with parentheses around, what do these mean.

Or can someone guide me to a doc where I can read up on this matter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers guys, you helped me a lot. To bad it was a duplicate, I was coming at this from another angle. I didn't know the right name for it, so I didn't know how to search for it.

The guy in the "duplicate" post actually knew what he was searching for, he just didn't know how to do it :P

Answer (score 5):

This is called [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting).

It forces $middleware to an array data type.  Some examples:

```
(array) [1,2] // [1,2]
(array) 1 // [1]
(array) stdClass{hello: world} // [hello => world]  (object to array pseudocode)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!